# Doctrine subquery syntax

Tags: doctrine

I need to reproduce with doctrine a AND statement from an sql query

> AND ((SELECT e2.candidature_id_ca FROM evaluateur_candidature e2 WHERE
>   e.candidature_id_ca = e2.candidature_id_ca AND  e2.role_evaluateur =
>   'evaluateur' ) IS NULL )

It's so easy to reproduce this with doctrine i tried :

```
    $query->andWhere('(SELECT e2.candidature_id_ca FROM evaluateur_candidature e2 WHERE
e.candidature_id_ca = e2.candidature_id_ca AND  e2.role_evaluateur = ?)' , 'evaluateur' , 'IS NULL ');
```

But i get

> Couldn't find class e2

Someone know how i could do it ? thanks in advance

UPDATE here the full doctrine query :

```
    $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->from('Candidature c')
                    ->innerJoin('c.RoleActeur ra_cand ON c.id_ca = ra_cand.id_ca AND ra_cand.id_role = 4')
                    ->innerJoin('ra_cand.Acteur ac_cand')
                    ->innerJoin('c.CandidatureActeur ca ON c.id_ca = ca.id_ca')
                    ->where('c.id_stca = 5');

    $query->leftJoin('c.EvaluateurCandidature ec');

    //here i would like to get the "Candidature collection" who not have records in the table EvaluateurCandidature when the column role_evaluateur is set to  "evaluation". 


    //$query->andWhere('ec.role_evaluateur = ? ) ? )', 'evaluateur' ,'IS NULL ');
  $query->andWhere('(SELECT e2.candidature_id_ca FROM evaluateur_candidature e2 WHERE
e.candidature_id_ca = e2.candidature_id_ca AND  e2.role_evaluateur = ?)' , 'evaluateur' , 'IS NULL ');
```

Comment: Can you post entity definitions also business requirement like what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: thanks for your reply i just updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your description you could include another condition on join `EvaluateurCandidature` to join only records where role_evaluateur is set to  "evaluation" after that select only records where id of `EvaluateurCandidature` is null

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                ->from('Candidature c')
                ->innerJoin('c.RoleActeur ra_cand ON c.id_ca = ra_cand.id_ca AND ra_cand.id_role = 4')
                ->innerJoin('ra_cand.Acteur ac_cand')
                ->innerJoin('c.CandidatureActeur ca ON c.id_ca = ca.id_ca')
                ->leftJoin("c.EvaluateurCandidature ec WITH ec.role_evaluateur = 'evaluation'")
                ->where('c.id_stca = 5')
                ->andWhere('ec.id IS NULL');
```

[WITH keyword](http://doctrine1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#with-keyword)